# Add fields to ACF repeater based on other repeater

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I've seen a few of these, but nothing really like what I'm working on. I have a client creating comparison charts/tables. Repeater #1 creates the titles for the (and therefore the number of) rows. Repeater #2 can create up to five columns to compare. Within Repeater 2 is Repeater #3, which corresponds to the titles in Repeater #1. I'd like a way to set the min and max number of rows for Repeater #3 to the row count for repeater #1 (so it's impossible for them to screw it up).

If I figure it out, I'll post the answer, but if anyone has a solution or ideas, would appreciate it.

Comment: each repeater has a Min/Maximum Rows option

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly I think this might work for you.

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-load_field/

```
function my_acf_load_field($repeater_3) {
    // Count Rows in Repeater 1
    $count = count(get_field('repeater_1', $pg_id));

    // Set Min & Max equal to count of Repeater 1
    $repeater_3['min'] = $count;
    $repeater_3['max'] = $count;

    // Return Field
    return $field;
}

add_filter('acf/load_field/name=repeater_3', 'my_acf_load_field');
```